# Совместное использование Laravel и Svetle возможно?

Tags: laravel, svelte

**Небольшое предисловие**

Веб-разработкой профессионально не занимаюсь, скорее для саморазвития. В качестве старта изучил связку `MODX Revo` + `Bootstrap 4`. И до некоторого времени хватало. Разработка тупых информативных сайтов ограниченной функциональности с помощью этого - просто на ура. Быстро и относительно несложно. И вот захотелось чего-то большего. Чтобы сайты не получались такими жирными, такими тормозными, с таким ограниченным UI. Начал разбираться ...

В качестве бэкэнда выбрал `Laravel`. Интуитивно понятный фрэймворк, прекрасный шаблонизатор, ну пока для себя (если не подскажете) лучшей альтернативы не вижу. А вот с фронтэндом сложнее. По сути я им никогда и не занимался. Да, JavaScript бегло читаю, в определенной части все понимаю. Вот также решил выбрать какой-то движок. Сперва выбор пал на `Angular`. Но дальнейшие "изыскания" заставили пропустить и `JQuery` как таковой, и `Angular`, и `React`, и `Vue`... и привели к `Svetle`.

**Вопрос**

Одна "загвоздка". Все прелесть `Svetle` - в предварительной компиляции. Вот собственно и возник вопрос - эти технологии можно ли как-то использовать совместно? И если "да", то какой порядок разработки вам видится?

Comment: Проблем нет, пишете фронт отдельно на Svelte, бэкенд на Laravel, аутентификация запросов - по токену (если надо) - JWT или Laravel Passport

Comment: А как быть с маршрутизацией - и там, и там вроде бы она есть? Хочется чего-то централизованного.

Comment: можно писать на sapper, там маршрутизация на файлах (как next или nuxt), можно машрутизатор поставить свой. На бэкенде прописывашь только `/api/*` маршруты, с фронта делаешь запросы к апи